# Co-registering mri with fdg of different sizes

Tags: mri

I want to co-register `fdg` images with `mri` images that have different sizes. I have tried using `SPM` but was not able to do it.

Can some one tell me the steps to follow?

Do I need to resize or resample one of the images?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this Q&A in stack overflow pretty much tells you how to go about it:

[Image registration of two volume with different number of slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892048/image-registration-of-two-volume-with-different-number-of-slices)